# Bam fails to make a sparse matrix?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am trying to make a binomial GAM with approx. 6.3 million rows of data (hence the `bam`). I have two random effects (40 and 7 levels) using `s(...,"re")`, 3 categorical variables (with 5 + 5 + 4 levels), and one cyclic smooth (`s(Hour, by = GroupAB, bs = "cc")`). GroupAB have 25 levels and is a concatenation between two of the previously mentioned variables, I included an additional interaction between these outside the smooth. Something like `(y~s(..,"re") + s(..,"re")  + s(Hour, by = GroupAB, "cc") + A * B + C, family ="binomial")`.

When I run the model i get the following error message:

```
Error in predict.gam(G, newdata = mf[ind, ], type = "lpmatrix", newdata.guaranteed = TRUE,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Which I have traced to bam attempting to make the sparse matrix (`sparse.matrix.model()` in https://github.com/cran/mgcv/blob/master/R/bam.r). Seeing that it used among others the `chunk.size=` argument of `bam()`, I started to play around with it. After increasing the chunck size from 10k to 75K I got the model running and giving reasonable results.

But why the error in the first place? Is there a trick to avoid this error message? Or is it to do with the data?